# WCF service without SSL but with Windows Group authentication

Tags: wcf, ssl, web-config, windows-authentication

We are trying to create a WCF service that is only accesible by specified windows groups. 
How can this be configured in the server web.config and the client configuration?

Note: We want to be able to control the windows groups who are allowed access in the server web.config not in code. Also, we dont want/need SSL at all.

Ive googled around and then best examples I can find are all like this...

[WCF Service, Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367653/wcf-service-windows-authentication)

But that doesnt explain how to limit access only to a specific group or groups.

Comment: why don't you want SSL? I know there are valid reasons why, but you should state them

Comment: Ok thats a good question. Basically this is an intranet application and the company doesnt want the overhead/costs of maintaining SSL certificates on the client machines. If this problem can only be solved with SSL then we might have to reconsider that - but I was hoping we could avoid it.

Comment: We are currently using wsHttpBinding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is the solution we came up with. Although it does involve a code change (adding the AspNetCompatibilityRequirements attribute) we can now acheive configuration of the groups/roles in the web.config file rather than hardcoding.

There are a number of steps to this...

1) Add the **aspNetCompatibilityEnabled** attribute into the serviceHostingEnvironment element and set to true, e.g....

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

This tells the WCF service to running in ASP.NET Compatibility Mode and participate fully in the ASP.NET HTTP request lifecycle. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx) for full details.

2) In the WCF code add **AspNetCompatibilityRequirements** attribute to the service class as per the link above and as specified in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.aspnetcompatibilityrequirementsattribute.aspx)...

```
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>
```

3) Now we can add the usual ASP **authorization** element in to restrict access to the specified groups/users (without the settings (1) and (2) above, this would be ignored by WCF)...

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow roles="MYDOMAIN\WCFAuthenticatedUsers" /> <-- allows access to users in this group
        <deny users="*" /> <-- denies access to all other users
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is intranet application you can use netTcpBinding:

```
<services>
   <service name="YourService"
      behaviorConfiguration="YourServiceBehavior">
      <endpoint 
         binding="netTcpBinding"
         bindingConfiguration="SecureTransportWindows"
         contract="YourContract" />
   </service>
</services>

<bindings>
   <binding name="SecureTransportWindows">
      <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
   </binding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="YourServiceBehavior">          
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseWindowsGroups" />
      </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviours>
```

And then in service code you can demand windows role:

```
class YourService : YourContract
{
    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="MYDOMAIN\Administrators")]
    public string SecuredOperation(string name)
    {
       return "secured operation";
    }
}
```

If you need to set it in config then you must implement custom authorization:

```
<behavior name="YourServiceBehavior">          
   <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom">            
      <authorizationPolicies>
         <add policyType="YourCustomAuthorizationPolicy"/>
      </authorizationPolicies>          
   </serviceAuthorization>
</behavior>
```

And in code implement IAuthorizationPolicy interface:

```
public class YourCustomAuthorizationPolicy : IAuthorizationPolicy
{
   //you need to check msdn 
}
```

Comment: Thanks jlp, this is helpful but we really would like to control the groups/roles who have access in the config file rather than hardcoded into the PrincipalPermission attribute in the code. We have now come up with a solution which I will write up as an alternative answer in case its of benefit to anyone else. Thanks